# Ideal sheaf of a point in $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, coherent-sheaves, projective-schemes

Let $k$ be a algebraically closed field, $X = \mathbb{P}^1_k = \mathrm{Proj} k[x,y]$ the projective space and $p = (ax+by) \in X$ a closed point. Let $\mathcal{I}_p = \ker( {\mathcal{O}_X \to p_* \mathcal{O}_{X,p}})$ the ideal sheaf of $p$, I want to prove that $\mathcal{I}_p \simeq \mathcal{O}_X(-1)$.

If I'm understanding it right, $p_* \mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is the skycraft sheaf at $p$ and
$$
\mathcal{I}_p(U) = 
\begin{cases}
\mathcal{O}_X(U) \quad &\text{if} p \notin U\\
\ker (\mathcal{O}_X(U) \to \mathcal{O}_{X,p})
\end{cases}
$$
where the last map is the natural insertion. In special
$$\mathrm{stalk}_p \mathcal{I}_p = 0$$
Then I really stuck in understand how $\mathcal{I}_p$ can be invertible because a locally free sheaf of rank $n$ has free stalks with the same rank.

Well, returning to original question, let $U_x = D_+(x)$ and $U_y=D_+(y)$ the canonical affine charts of $\mathbb{P}^1$. Let's suppose $p \in U_x$ (i.e., $b \neq 0$), then
$$
\mathcal{I}_p(U_x) = \ker (\mathcal{O}_X(U_x) \to p_*\mathcal{O}_p(U_x)) = \ker ( k[x,y]_{(x)} \to k[x,y]_{((ax+by))} ) = 0
$$
Which just doesn't make sense, am I getting it wrong?

Comment: you are stuck I believe because what you should be looking at is $ker(\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow k(p):= p_*(\mathcal{O}_{X,p}/\mathfrak{m}_p\mathcal{O}_{X,p})$ and not the map to the stalk...

Comment: Thank you a lot, it worked now. I spent the night trying and getting stuck and a two-line comment saved me.

Comment: happy to know it helped

Comment: @ThadeuHenriqueCardoso There is also intuition here that may help you to avoid similar mistakes in the future: If we consider $\left\{p\right\}$ as a variety on its own, what are the $k$-valued functions? Well, there's not really anything to specify other than an element of $k$ (the value of the function at the only point in sight), so $\mathcal O_p \cong k(p) = k$ (or this is by definition since $p$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Spec}k$). On the other hand the stalk $\mathcal O_{X,p}$, as you know, contains a lot of information about how $p$ sits inside $X$, so is far "larger"...

Comment: ...(in particular it contains a copy of the one-variable polynomial ring over $k$).

Comment: Thank you @TabesBridges. And actually, for the one-point space {p}  to be an integral scheme, it has to be the affine scheme of a field.  I was out of my mind.